# php mysql request db date each reload

Tags: php, mysql, request

On my site I need to request a date/time every page reload.

The reason why is because I need to perform a database action if an hour or more has passed since the last time it was done.

Something like this (pseudo code)

```
select time from database table
if (time < hour_ago) {
   do this + set time = now
   }
```

My question is, is this the best way to do this? Would it be quicker if the time was stored in a txt file instead? Or another way?

I'm already using a database connection each page but just wondering if it's worth a query just to get one date.

Comment: Does this need to be run by different users? Could it be stored in a session? / Does this need to be run automatically? Could it be a scheduled task? / Does it have performance implications? / Could you do the check *and update* in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases are a good way to store persistent information. If you are already using a DB then I would see no reason to put this anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

> is this the best way to do this?

Definitely no.

There should be no such "hourly database actions at all.